# How to access the vaadin application session outside the scope of the components?

Tags: gwt, liferay, vaadin

I developed a system of tabs like a browser in my application vaadin. However, I can not provide my `TabManager` outside the scope of the components. I can not use a singleton because it would be available for all users, which is not ideal. It would be interesting to provide this in a kind of user session but I did not find anything like that.

I am developing my application in scala but I believe this is not relevant.

Has anyone had this problem? How were you able to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a reference to your applications with com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractWebApplicationContext.getApplicationContext(httpSession).getApplications()

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood it correctly, you are looking for a way to have something like a user session for each user using your application.

In this case consider using ThreadLocals. Follow [this link](http://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/ThreadLocal%20Pattern) for the wiki page.